# How to schedule message popups and show only the last message?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I create following form and I click 3 buttons (randomly). After I click a button, it must show a related message after 3 seconds from clicking it. But if I had clicked another button in the meanwhile, then the related message of that button has to be shown and the previous message in the queue has to be canceled.

As an example, if I click `button1` at 11.30.00, then related message should pop up only at 11.30.03 like "You clicked : 1 before 3 Seconds". But if I click another `button2` before the 11.30.03, say at 11.30.02 then related message should pop up at 11.30.05 like "You clicked : 2 before 3 Seconds" and the message scheduled for 11.30.03 has to be canceled.

This is my code:

```
private int signal = 0;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signal = 1;
    displayMessage(signal);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signal = 2;
    displayMessage(signal);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signal = 3;
    displayMessage(signal);
}

private void displayMessage(int number) 
{       
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked : "+number+ "before 3 Seconds");
}
```

Comment: And what is happening now with the code? What have you tried? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: start a timer. Keep changing signal value, and when time is equal to 3 seconds, show up the messagebox from tick event

Comment: Please describe more detailed what the problem is, exactly what is not working as expected? Without a better explanation, your question might be closed.

Comment: now I click one of the button it just shows the related message. as an example I click 2nd btn after the 3seconds I need to show the message but without spend 3 seconds if click button 1 after the 3seconds it need to show related message please sir if you have an idea please tell me.

Comment: @mssb could you repeat that again in proper sentence. Try putting proper punctuations like periods and commas appropriately. its hard to follow u actually

Comment: if I click one of the button it just shows the related message.that thing already working. but the problem(what I need to add) :(as a example) step1: I click button2 so output should be related message but after 3 seconds later. step2: if I click button3 without waiting 3seconds(after doing step1) output should be the "You clicked : 3 before 3 Seconds" sir sorry for my english if you can give me a solution

Comment: @mssb ok so what you mean is if you click on a button, it should show the related message only after 3 seconds right? Suppose I click button1 at 11.30.00, then related message should pop up only at 11.30.33, is it? OK i get the rest of the part.

Comment: yes you are correct,but if you click  another button(button3) before the 11.30.33 (you clicked 11.30.32) then related message should pop up only at 11.30.35

Comment: @mssb so that means u get two messageboxes, one at 11.30.33 and 11.30.35 right? Is that what you want? wouldnt it become too much if user clicks too many buttons in quick succession?

Comment: no no only need to show last message box.

Comment: @mssb see my original answer, its a simple logic to tweak from there on. Just reset the timer there instead of disposing it! On SO, you should so some original effort and then tell us. Otherwise people will be generally hostile at you. If  u r still unsuccessful, tell me I would give a working solution

Comment: actually I tried your your answer but when I click one button it repeats periodically. message need to show only onetime. if you have a time please help me. how ever I really appreciate your effort. thank you.

Comment: @mssb I have updated my answer, please see it.

Comment: @mssb I wasn't asking you to merely try out answers here. Try something your own, related to or unrelated to answers here. And tell us why its not working for you. At present you are saying "I get this, but I want that". Instead say something like "how to delay the messagebox" or "how to stop the timer appropriately as that's the trouble I see" etc.. I am not trashing, just saying, good luck and welcome to SO :)

Comment: @mssb with more time on programming you will learn more. One thing, you need to address people when posting a comment to someone, only then I will be notified. so in your comments to mine, tag me like this: "@nawfal thank you its working"

Comment: @nawfal thank you very much for your advices and also spend your valuable time for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a timer. Keep changing signal value according to button click, and when time elapsed is equal to 3 seconds, show up the messagebox from tick event. Set the timer interval according to your need and that will be reflected in the "related message".

```
int signal = 0;
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //----------------------- other parts of code ---------------------

    // at last
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
    t.Start();
}

void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (signal == 0)
        return;

    t.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked: " + signal + " before " + t.Interval + " Seconds");
    signal = 0;
    t.Start(); //move this to top of msgbox if you want timer to be reset right after poppin the msgbox.
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signal = 1;
    t.Stop();
    t.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signal = 2;
    t.Stop();
    t.Start();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signal = 3; 
    t.Stop();
    t.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set buttons `Tag`:

```
button1.Tag = 1;
button2.Tag = 2;
button3.Tag = 3;
```

then set `Click` event:

```
button1.Click += button_Click;
button2.Click += button_Click;
button3.Click += button_Click;
```

on the `Click` event:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signal = (int) ((Button))sender.Tag;
    displayMessage(signal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a place where someone is just going to give you an answer, do some research into the area then post if you get stuck.
you want to create a static timer and check if its finished within each event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx